# How can I know what application/service is launching a short-duration console program on startup?

Tags: windows

Every time I log in my Windows Server after boot, a Console window is shown for a very short period of time. I've been unable to record a video to read what's displayed in the console to guess what background application/service is launching it. Is there any way to know who is invoking the console?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft ProcMon or Sysmon both will identify the process starting the application, and the application and location.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/sysmon